# What does the response be "bad value" in mongodb while using query parameters in the url and how to resolve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 2,
    "codeName": "BadValue",
    "name": "MongoError"
}
```

I'm getting this error when I use query parameters skip and limit in the url.

`localhost:5000/api/posts?skip=0&limit=5`

This is the url I've written.

```
postsController.list = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query)
    // let skip = Number(req.query.skip) || 0
    // let limit = Number(req.query.limit) || 5
    const { skip = 0, limit = 5 } = req.query
    Post.find({}, {skip: Number(skip), limit: Number(limit) }).populate('comments')
        .then((posts) => {
            res.json(posts)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.json(err)
        })
}
```

And the code is as given above.

Comment: Are you also using mongoose or just the mongodb driver?

Comment: yes, I'm using mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using mongoose, you need to pass `null` as second argument:

```
Post.find({}, null, {skip: Number(skip), limit: Number(limit) })     ...
```

That argument is the [query projection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), which defines what fields to include or exclude from the query.

However, you can chain [.skip()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip) and [.limit()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) methods, in this way:

```
Post.find({})
    .skip(Number(skip))
    .limit(Number(limit))
    .populate('comments')
    .then((posts) => {
        res.json(posts)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.json(err)
    })
```